# Create an entity

Tags: database, list, symfony, entity

I made a web-application with Symfony2 in which a registered user can upload a file through a form.
With the file, the user save also an information about that file, that represents the "mission" related to it.

Now I set the "mission information" into the "user object"; so, when the user store the file, the controller retrieve the information about the mission and associate it to the file.

The user entity is then:

```
class UserOperator extends User
{

    protected $id;

    protected $name;

    private $mission;
```

with annotations, setters and getters.

And my createAction to store a file is:

```
   public function createAction(Request $request)
   {                 
             $product = new Product();
  // ...  
             $product->setMission($this->getUser()->getMission());

             $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
                 ->add('name', 'text')
  // ...                       
                 ->add('save', 'submit')
  // ... 
                 ->getForm();
```

The problem is that if I want to change name or erase or modify the mission, I have to change all the users associated to that mission. I prefer to create a "mission entity" in which store all and only the users that are involved in that mission; when a user stores a file, the controller query the database the missions available and let the user choose only the missions associated to him, and store the file with the chosen mission.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Making a recap, my "mission entity" should only comprehend

```
$id
$name
$description (a textarea)
$userlist
```

Now I have an entity called user and an entity called $product. Into the entity $user is stored a issue called "mission": when the user upload a file with a specific form, the controller also save the mission associated with the user. Now I don't have a "mission entity", and I don't know how to do it, how to associate many user to the mission entity.

I hope it is clear.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I will show you. I think I know what you want to do.

First of all, lets make the mission entity:

```
namespace YOURNAMESPACE;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mission implements MissionInterface {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="YOURNAMESPACE\User", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setUsers(Collection $users){
        $this -> users = $users;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addUser(UserInterface $user){
        $this -> users -> add($user);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsers(){
        return $this -> users;
    }

// setter + getter
}

namespace YOURNAMESPACE;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="YOURNAMESPACE\Mission", mappedBy="users")
     */
    protected $missions;

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> missions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setMissions(Collection $missions){
        $this -> missions = $missions;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addMission(MissionInterface $mission){
        $this -> missions -> add($mission);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMissions(){
        return $this -> missions;
    }

// setter + getter
}
```

Note: return $this; is not necessary, but can be used to combine calls like $this -> set1() -> set2().

Edit: You wanted the code for the interfaces. I think this is basic stuff, but I hate uncompleted solutions, so here are the interfaces:

```
namespace YOURNAMESPACE;

use SOMENAMESPACE\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

interface MissionInterface {
    /**
     * make some documentation please
     */
    public function getUsers();
    /**
     * make some documentation please
     */
    public function addUser(UserInterface $user);
    /**
     * make some documentation please
     */
    public function setUsers(Collection $users);
    // + other functions
}
```

You should also create your own UserInterface that extends the UserInterface of Symfony and adds your new methods to it.

Now your users are associated with the missions. Each user can have multiple missions, each mission can have multiple users.

Comment: Yes, it is! Last doubt; do I have to change the setter and getter in the user?
Now I have
        public function setMission($mission)
Do i Have to write
    public function setMission($missions)
?

Comment: I changed the code a bit. Now you have some examples for valid setters and getters

Comment: Why do you implement MissionInterface? I don't have it, and when I update the database it displays an error.

Comment: If you can specify the type of a parameter you should do it. The software is much more stable then. So normally you'd write addMission(Mission $mission). But sometimes Doctrine/Symfony loads data from cache. In this case the class is not the class itself, but a proxy class (__proxies.../...). addMission would fail, because class proxy is not instanceof class Mission. But if you ask for instanceof interface, it wouldn't fail, cause the proxy class also implements the methods of the MissionInterface. You have to program the MissionInterface, it's not a Symfony-class!

Comment: But actually I have two kind of user,UserOperator and UserGroundStation, and both of them extend User. 
About implement Interface I don't find help online, can you suggest me the documentation?

Comment: Does each user have a mission or only specific users? If only specific users have a mission, you have to make a parent class called user and extend the class user with a class called missionUser for example. Only the mission user has the association, not the core user itself

Comment: The GroundStationUser is the user that uploads the file, the OperatorUser is the user allowed to see the files stored. Both of them extends UserClasse. Every user have one or more mission associated.

Comment: Ok so put the association into the base user class. Extend the base user class with the classes OperatorUser and GroundStationUser. Use the annotation @ORM\MappedSuperclass() for the base user class and make it abstract.

Comment: Done, but the problems still remains: when I update in the command windows the database appears:
Interface 'Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\MissionInterface' not found

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem.

- You got an entity called file
- You got an entity called mission
- You got an entity called user
- Each file has exactly one mission. This association is necessary.
- Each mission has multiple users
- Each user that is associated with a mission can edit, update, delete this mission

Now you want to change some properties of the mission, for example the name. Normally it wouldn't be any problem. 
So why do you have to "change all the users associated to that mission"? Is this a requirement or a consequence of your code?

Comment: Now I have an entity called user and an entity called $product. Into the entity $user is stored a issue called "mission": when the user upload a file with a specific form, the controller also save the mission associated with the user.
Now I don't have a "mission entity", and I don't know how to do it, how to associate many user to the mission entity.